# createFromFormat giving me wrong results

Tags: php, date, date-format

I want to convert date form from d/m/Y to Y-m-d with timezone offset. I am able to convert from d/m/Y to Y-m-d with this code:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date);
$date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

This works to some degree but when i come across date like these:

```
echo DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:m:s', '19/07/2017 00:00:00');
results is 2016-12-19 00:00:00.000000
echo DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:m:s', '20/07/2017 22:51:17');
results is false
```

**EDITED**
Now using the suggested format

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', '19/07/2017 00:00:00');
```

**Expected Result:**

```
06/06/2017 00:00:00 => 2017-06-06 00:00:00.000000
06/06/2017 12:31:34 => 2017-06-06 12:31:34.000000
08/06/2017 21:59:21 => 2017-08-06 21:59:21.000000
19/07/2017 00:00:00 => 2018-07-07 00:00:00.000000 wrong!
20/07/2017 22:51:17 => 2018-08-07 22:51:17.000000 wrong!
21/07/2017 23:39:23 => 2018-09-07 23:39:23.000000 wrong!
27/07/2017 02:46:14 => 2019-03-07 02:46:14.000000 wrong!
```

Comment: It should be `d/m/Y H:i:s` use `H` for `24hour` format.

Comment: Cheers getting somewhere now but it still giving the wrong result e.g 30/07/2017 00:00:00 turn into 2016-12-07 00:00:00.000000

Comment: @Photonic: You use `m` for minutes instead of `i`. Sahil edited his comment, maybe you didn't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `H` and `i` instead. Also You can't echo an object use `print_r` instead.

[**Try with an example**](https://eval.in/895292)

> `H` for 24 hour format.
>
> `i` for Minutes with leading zeros

**Change this to:**

```
echo DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:m:s', '19/07/2017 00:00:00');
```

**This:**

```
print_r(DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', '19/07/2017 00:00:00'));
```

*For getting specific format*

```
$dateObject=DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', '19/07/2017 00:00:00');
echo $dateObject->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Comment: Works for some but 23/08/2017 18:08:02 => 2018-11-08 18:08:02.000000 | 24/08/2017 22:42:56 => 2018-12-08 22:42:56.000000 and many more

Comment: @Photonic Can you share your expected format? you want.

Comment: d/m/Y H:i:s to Y-m-d H:i:s is my expected result. Anyway some result is way off, like years, month and days.

Comment: @Photonic Can you try this https://eval.in/895295 . It is working fine.

Comment: Yes thats working now thank you so much @Sahil Gulati

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', '20/07/2017 22:51:17');
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

To explain *why* this is giving you those results:

Your date format string contains `m` twice, the second of which is reading the "minutes" portion of the time. This is overwriting the previous, correct month value. Since your first string (`19/07/2017 00:00:00`) has a zero for the minutes, your `DateTime` object is being initialised to the "0th" month - in PHP this causes the date to roll back one month into the previous year, so you're seeing December 2016.

Your second string (`20/07/2017 22:51:17`) is failing because you're using `h` to parse a 24hr time - this will fail when parsing any number higher than 12.

As explained in other answers, the correct format string to use for those dates is `d/m/Y H:i:s`.